# How do I loop though the length of an array inside of another array in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop, pygame

I need to loop through the keys array, which is a group of arrays within one array, I use two for loops. One to access the different arrays, and then one to loop through the contents of each array. When I get to the `"for j in range(5):"`, which is the second loop, it says `"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'length'"`, though it is not one complete string but separate character in an array, which you can check out in `"keys."` What is the right way to loop through everything in the keys array?

```
# import pygame
import os, sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

# initialize game engine
pygame.init()

#WINDOw
width=600
height=400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("keyboard")

filler = 0;
keys = [['a','b','c','d','e','f'],['g','h','i','j''k'],['l','m','n','o','p'],['q','r','s','t','u'],['v','w','x','y','z']];


animation_increment=10
fps=20
dead=False
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
x = 0

class keyBoard(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    #code
    def keyDraw(self):
        for i in range(5):
            for j in keys[i]:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,255),(60*i + 10,60*j, 50,50));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your question as posted:

```
   for j in len(keys[i]):
       print(keys[i][j])
       # print individual characters
```

I suspect that you want the elements, not the indices, but `enumerate` gives you both:

```
def keyDraw(self):
    for i, char_list in enumerate(keys):
        for j, char in enumerate(char_list):
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,(255,0,255),(60*i + 10,60*j, 50,50))
```

I can't adjust your usage of the list elements, since you didn't provide any.

`i` is your index into `keys`; `char_list` will iterate through the character lists, being equivalent to `keys[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

The length of an list can be get by [`len`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len). Lists in a list can be traversed by:

```py
for i in range(len(keys)):
    for j in range(len(keys[i])):
```

Another option is to use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```py
for i, keylist in enumerate(keys):
    for j, letter in enumerate(keylist):
```